# Adding .toggle() to cell content

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to ask, is it possible to attach a .toggle() function in a certain and specific cell in jqGrid? It's possible to change a cell's contents by using setCell, but from what I've tried, it only changes the CSS attributes of it.

```
grid.jgGrid("setCell", cellId, colName, "", {visibility: 'hidden'});
```

Is there a way for me to show/hide/blink my text inside the cell on GridComplete?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could change the color of text to transparent on cell click. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCgTm/)

It toggles every cell data. You can customize according to your requirement

jqgrid **oncellselect** function:

```
    onCellSelect : function(rowid,iCol, cellcontent,e){
        var td = $("#"+rowid).find("td");
        var reqTd = td[iCol];

        if($(reqTd).attr("class") == 'transp'){
              $(reqTd).removeClass("transp");
        } else {
            $(reqTd).addClass("transp");


        }

    }
```

**CSS**

```
.transp {
    color: transparent;
};
```